# Pawn-Promotions

Tags: pawn-promotion

The Pawn Promotion, I read that: "A pawn may be promoted to any piece.  (NOTE: A common misconception is that pawns may only be exchanged for a piece that has been captured.  That is NOT true.)"  So, does this mean that if your queen hasn't been captured and you make it to the other side to promote your pawn, you can actually have, say, 2 queens on the board?

Comment: This isn't an exact duplicate. The other question is about promoting two pawns, while this question is about promoting when your queen hasn't been captured.

Answer (score 3):

You may promote to a queen, a bishop, a knight or a rook of your own colour. Yes, you can end up with up to 9 queens in a game in principle.

Comment: Or even ten Knights, Rooks, or Bishops!